# Getting Error when trying to save Django Model to My Sql Dtatabase

Tags: python, mysql, django, django-models

Hi I'm getting this error when I try to save a model AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'startswith.  
Basicly the program should show a list of all users. But even though in the table there are already some entries. The table I show on the Web side is empty and no error is shown.

models.py:

```
from django.db import models
from django.db import connections



class Users(models.Model):
    identifier  = models.CharField(primary_key=True,max_length=100)
    accounts = models.TextField()
    group = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    inventory = models.TextField()
    job = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    job_grade = models.IntegerField()
    loadout = models.TextField()
    position = models.CharField(max_length=300)
    firstname = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    lastname = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    dateofbirth = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    sex = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    height = models.IntegerField()
    skin = models.TextField()
    status = models.TextField()
    is_dead = models.SmallIntegerField()
    phone_number = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    class Meta:
        db_table = "users",
```

views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from .models import Users

# Create your views here.
def show(request):


    newUser = Users(
    identifier  = "abc",
    accounts = "[]",
    group = "admin",
    inventory = "[]",
    job = "police",
    job_grade = 3,
    loadout ="[]",
    position = "da",
    firstname = "swpw",
    lastname = "wwww",
    dateofbirth = "wolplwodokwowdüp",
    sex = "m",
    height = 78,
    skin = "[]",
    status = "[]",
    is_dead = 0,
    phone_number = "hallo",)

    newUser.save()
    return render(request,'acp/show.html',{'user':users})
```

Comment: Remove the trailling comma in `db_table = "users",`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the `db_table` it expects a *string*, not a singleton tuple. By removing the trailing comma, you thus wrap the item in a singleton tuple:

```
class Users(models.Model):
    # …
    
    class Meta:
        db_table = 'users'  # ← remove the trailing comma
```

If the table already exists, you should avoid managing the table yourself, you thus add [**`managed=True`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/models/options/#managed) to the `Meta` options:

```
class Users(models.Model):
    # …
    
    class Meta:
        db_table = 'users'
        managed = True
```

---

> **Note**: normally a Django model is given a *singular* name, so `User` instead of <s>`Users`</s>.